# for loop / if condition in shell script

Tags: bash, shell

I've never done shell script before and now I'm running into a simple problem...
I have a for loop which executes every time the run.sh script. To see how far the script has already run I want to print e.g. every 5000 the actual index.

```
$counter = 0
for ((  i = 0 ;  i <= 5000;  i++  ))do
    if ($i =  $counter); then
            echo "$counter"
            counter=$(counter+1000)
    fi
./run.sh
done
```

running this piece of code gives me the following error

```
./for_loop.sh: line 1: =: command not found
./for_loop.sh: line 3: 0: command not found
```

I have also tried to init the variable counter with

```
declare -i counter = 0
```

which gives me the following error

```
./for_loop.sh: line 1: declare: `=': not a valid identifier
```

Comment: In Bash, there are two assignment operators, `=` and `let =`, so you may assign the first counter with `counter=0` or `let counter=0`. `let` is meant to be used only with numbers while `=` works with any string.

Comment: You need to read a tutorial on shell syntax, you have many basic syntax errors.

Comment: For instance, you don't put `$` before the variable name when assigning, only when reading it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't really need two counters.  A single counter will suffice:

```
for (( counter = 0; counter <= 5000; counter++ ))
do
    if (( counter % 1000 == 0 ))
    then
            echo "$(( counter / 1000 ))"
    fi
    ./run.sh
done
```

This executes `run.sh` 5000 times and prints the counter value every 1000 iterations.  Note that `%` is the modulus operator which computes remainder after division and `/` is the integer division operator.

Comment: thanks for your nice solution!
the command echo "%(( counter / 1000 ))" prints actually %(( counter / 1000 )) and not the result of counter/1000. Do you know where the problem is?

Comment: Oops!  `%(( counter / 1000 ))` should read `$(( counter / 1000 ))`.  Replace the `%` with a `$`.  I corrected my answer.

Comment: oh of course... could have found it out by myself :) thx again

Answer (score 4):

Line 1 should be: (No $, no extra spaces around '=')

```
counter=0
```

Line 3 should be: (Square brackets, '-eq' because '=' is for string equality)

```
if [ $i -eq $counter ]
```

Line 5 should be: (Double parentheses)

```
counter=$((counter+1000))
```

Comment: In the for-loop, there should also be a semicolon between `))` and `do`, or `do` should be on the next line.

Comment: You are right, but for some reason the `for (( .. ))do` runs fine on my machine (bash 3.2.17).

Comment: What about `for (( .. )) do`, that is, with a space between the last closing parenthesis and `do`?  Perhaps Bash accepts the closing parenthesis as a delimiter replacement for the `;`.

Comment: That also works. I guess the `for (()) do` is easy enough to parse. But I agree it is bad style to omit the semicolon or newline here.

Comment: Line 3 could also be `if ((i == counter)); then` (just double the parentheses and the equal sign and you can omit or retain the dollar signs). Line 5 could be `(( counter += 1000 ))`. Also, in line 1 there shouldn't be a space *after* the equal sign either.

Comment: @Dennis You are right on all counts: like in perl, there's more than one way to do it. I usually write POSIX sh instead of bash. And I removed the space after the '='.

Comment: @Dennis:  This is form of if-statement condition that I used in my answer, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3422827/for-loop-if-condition-in-shell-script/3422983#3422983.

Comment: @Derek: Yep, that's one of the reasons I upvoted you earlier.

Answer (score 1):

In line 3 I believe you have mistaken assignment `=` for equality `==`

http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Arithmetic